# Как работать с mp3 файлами?

Tags: android, mp3, c++

Кроме общей информации, количество каналов/сэмпл рэйт и т.д. Мне нужно считать сами звуковые данные, я так понимаю, в виде массивов.

Возможно, есть простая открытая либа, которая примерно только для таких целей?

Answer (score 1):

Вроде с помощью [lame](https://github.com/intervigilium/liblame) или [mpg123](http://www.mpg123.de/faq.shtml) можно декодировать mp3 и получить PCM данные звуковые. Вот только все подобные либы будут долго работать (секунд 20 на 1 песню средней длины) в силу отсутствия аппаратной поддержки...

Comment: секунд 20 - многовато. С wav файлами намного быстрее происходит вычитка даже больших файлов, я так понимаю, это специфика mp3 или есть еще решения для быстрого декодирования?

Comment: @Максим_12345, wav читается быстро, так как там дорожки не закодированы вообще. Для чего вам необходимо декодировать mp3?

Comment: Для анализа звука, вернее там несколько алгоритмов анализа звука, все они завязаны на "чистые" значения в виде массивов. Поэтому ищу наиболее подходящий вариант для обработки mp3.

Comment: @Максим_12345, я ещё пробовал libmad, он пошустрее. Если же вам чисто Java решение надо, то только про JLayer знаю. Но эти решения всё равно слишком медленные.

Comment: тут не java, а С++ , я так понимаю lame(пусть даже медленный) подойдет для этих целей?

Comment: @Максим_12345, у меня даже C++'шные решения десятки секунд декодировали mp3 файлы более 3 минут длиной.

Comment: Suvitruf  - спасибо за оперативную помощь. 
Буду пробовать с lame разобраться, а там уже смотреть на производительноть.

Comment: @Максим_12345, не за что. Удачи (;